# NuxtJS ChartJS Gradient Color doesnt apply

Tags: chart.js, nuxt.js

I wrote in the mounted function:

```
this.gradient = this.$refs.canvas[0].$el.childNodes[0]
  .getContext('2d')
  .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450)
this.gradient.addColorStop(0, '#F44336')
this.gradient.addColorStop(0.3, '#F50057')
this.gradient.addColorStop(0.6, '#FF4081')
this.gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FF9100')
```

and in the function where I set the values for the charts:

```
datasets: [
      {
        label: service.name,
        backgroundColor: this.gradient,
        responsive: true,
        data: service.statusdatavalue
      }
    ]
```

There are no Console Errors nor others.

The result is always the same:

[image: always red]

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made the gradient the way below.

```
datasets: [{
    label: service.name,
    backgroundColor: this.gradient,
    responsive: true,
    data: service.statusdatavalue,
    fill: true.   // here!
}]
```